# Is there a way to resize the legend items of a discrete choropleth created using Plotly?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python, r-plotly, plotly.js

I'm using Python, if helpful, though I believe any solution would be language agnostic.  I've created a discrete choropleth mapbox using plotly.express, but when exporting at high resolutions the legend items (both font and coloring) become effectively unreadable.  If I recall, Plotly creates discrete figures by overlaying multiple traces, so not sure whether there's something we can do at the trace or figure level to fix.

Happy to share code if helpful, though I'm not actually updating the legend in anyway yet, so I don't think it adds anything.

[Hi-res map output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26ghj.jpg)

[Std map output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX5Y2.jpg)

Code:

```
DISCRETE = 11

def gen_colorscale(obs, color="viridis"):
    color = px.colors.sample_colorscale(color, obs)
    p1 = tuple(zip(np.linspace(0, 1, obs+1)[:-1], color))
    p2 = tuple(zip(np.linspace(0, 1, obs+1)[1:], color))
    cs = []
    for a, b in zip(p1, p2):
        cs.append(a)
        cs.append(b)
    return cs

cs = gen_colorscale(DISCRETE)

# color range
cr = [0, 10000]
# tick vals
v = np.linspace(*cr, DISCRETE)
vt = (
    pd.DataFrame(v, columns=["v"])
    .apply(lambda v: (v / 10 ** 3).round(1))
    .apply(lambda v: v.astype(str) + "k to " + v.shift(-1).astype(str) + "k")
    .values
)
vt[0] = v[0].astype(str) + " to " + (v[1] / 10 ** 3).round(1).astype(str) + "k"
vt[-1] = ">" + (v[-1] / 10 ** 3).round(1).astype(str) + "k"

fig = px.choropleth_mapbox(
    df,
    geojson=counties,
    locations="fips",
    color="migration",
    range_color=[cr[0], cr[1] + cr[1]/(DISCRETE-1)],
    color_continuous_scale=cs,
    labels={"migration": "Migration (k)"},
    center={"lat": 37.0902, "lon": -95.7129},
    zoom=4.2,
    opacity=1.0,
    mapbox_style="white-bg",
)
fig.update_layout(
    mapbox_style="mapbox://styles/ryangilland/ckwqzs8ck0h5f14nybww9c5ts",
    mapbox_accesstoken=token,
    coloraxis_colorbar=dict(
        tickvals=np.linspace(cr[0]+cr[1]/(DISCRETE-1)/2,cr[1] + cr[1]/(DISCRETE-1)/2,DISCRETE),
        ticktext=vt,
        len=0.8,
        thickness=50,
        xanchor="right",
        x=1.0,
        bgcolor="rgba(22,33,49,1)",
        tickfont=dict(color="rgba(255,255,255,1)"),
    ),
    margin=dict(l=0, r=0, b=50, t=75, pad=4),
    paper_bgcolor="rgba(8,18,23,1)",
    plot_bgcolor="rgba(8,18,23,1)",
)
fig.show()
```

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNu98.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- looking at this in an alternative way.  https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/#constructing-a-discrete-or-discontinuous-color-scale
- hence you can use discrete buckets to create a color scale
- this I would then expect works well on hi-res screens as color bar uses whole height of screen
- if there is no need to use **tickvals** or **ticktext** solution is far simpler

```
import geopandas as gpd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

gdf = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_lowres")).set_index("iso_a3")

DISCRETE = 6
# build discrete continuous colorscale
cs = [
    (a, px.colors.sample_colorscale("viridis", b)[0])
    for a, b in zip(
        np.repeat(np.linspace(0, 1, DISCRETE + 1), 2)[1:-1],
        np.repeat(np.linspace(0, 1, DISCRETE + 1), 2),
    )
]
# color range
cr = [0, gdf["pop_est"].quantile(.95)]
# tick vals
v = np.linspace(*cr, DISCRETE+1)
vt = (
    pd.DataFrame(v, columns=["v"])
    .apply(lambda v: (v / 10 ** 6).round(0).astype(int))
    .apply(lambda v: v.astype(str) + "M to " + v.shift(-1).astype(str) + "M")
    .values
)
px.choropleth_mapbox(
    gdf,
    geojson=gdf.__geo_interface__,
    locations=gdf.index,
    color="pop_est",
    color_continuous_scale=cs,
    range_color=cr,
).update_layout(
    mapbox={"style": "carto-positron", "zoom": .5},
    coloraxis={"colorbar": {"tickvals": v[1:] - v[1]/2, "ticktext":vt}},
    margin={"l":0,"r":0,"t":0,"b":0}
)
```

[image]

Comment: This was very helpful!  Just building on this, since this is somewhat of a disguised continuous scale, is there anyway to have one of the color ranges be for a single point?  For instance if I wanted to have one color just for entries that were equal to zero, then the next color for >0 and < 22M and so on.  I'm guessing no, but maybe there's someway to trick the scale?  I was able to cheat to get a ">130.0M" bucket at the top.

I added my current code to the original, which helps generate the image I added (Alaska and Hawaii are added separately and pasted over in my script),